# chart.js Doughnut anticlockwise animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, chart.js

I'm trying to change the animation from right to left since it's for negative values

left value should be -30 and left value 0

Is it possible to change the animation to anticlockwise? The only way I found is using CSS

```
transform: scaleX(-1);
```

but the result is not ok because it also reverse the text in the middle...

https://jsfiddle.net/sincos/u8goLmgt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to delay the time you set the actual value and set it only after the initial graph is loaded.

```
    setInterval(function() {
    data.datasets[0].data[1] = 60;
    data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[1] = "#F7464A";
    promisedDeliveryChart.update();
    }, 1000);
```

Here is how it looks in action: https://jsfiddle.net/u8goLmgt/2/